# Connect to Oracle running on my laptop from AWS DMS

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-dms

I have been trying to do simple POC for a data migration from oracle db running on my laptop (localhost) to AWS Redshift cluster, using AWS Data Migration Services.

I am able to connect to Redshift cluster from AWS SCT, was able to create schemas successfully, but when trying to migrate data from DMS, am unable to establish connection to my localhost oracle endpoint.

Am getting following error message:

> Error Details: [errType=ERROR_RESPONSE, status=1022307,
>   errMessage=ORA-12541: TNS:no listener OCI error., errDetails=]

Looks like we need to set up port forwarding and point to localhost:1521 (oracle running at localhost/port number).  I have tried configuring foxyproxy, but seems am missing something and still am unable to establish connection.  I have limited knowledge on foxyproxy/firewall settings please.

### Listener configuration:

```
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

### tnsnames.ora for localhost:

```
ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

**My oracle server is running on Windows environment, on a laptop.**

Appreciate any help please, since am struck with this for 2 days, and looking for a help/solution.  Let me know if any information required on

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your getting a no TNS-Listener I believe you're already getting a connection to the laptop or you would receive a different error.

Are you sure the listener is started?

What is your Oracle Home directory and is it the same place as the listener and ora files?